# JavaScript version of System.Text.RegularExpressions?

Tags: javascript, .net

I'm looking to emulate the System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace in JavaScript as I'm replacing a Silverlight product with a JavaScript version. It needs to continue to run .NET regular expressions, as that's been its claim to fame.

I've looked at three .NET to JavaScript compilers : JSIL, SharpKit, and DuoCode. None of them have full support for this namespace.

Does anyone know of a solution out there for this? My last resort could be to move the Regex processing server-side and use Ajax. But I really don't want to do that if I don't have to.

Comment: What is not provided by the native [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) or a literal `/pattern/i`?

Comment: There are differences in RegexOptions, as well as backreferences and balanced matching support. The other option would be for me to dedicate a lot of time to perform the translation myself. This namespace is open source and so I could theoretically rewrite the whole thing in JavaScript.

Comment: Sadly, although you can _backreference_ capture groups using `\n` where _n_ is the group number, you can't _lookback_ and you can't easily _balance match_ because _JavaScript_ doesn't have possessive quantifiers i.e. `?+`. If you want these behaviours you may end up needing a custom _RegExp_ implementation which isn't going to be fast :(

Comment: @PaulS. Yeah and it's important that it matches the behavior of .NET 100% because this application is advertised as a .NET Regex Tester.

Comment: If you're advertising your site that way, perhaps AJAX is the best way to do it.

Comment: In this case I'd recommend using .NET as the platform which runs the test and passing the results back somehow, make sure it's set up so the most horrific and malicious patterns don't kill your server though.